# When I run my code for my iOS app, it stops as if I set a breakpoint (no errors) and won't keep running

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

After I hit Run, it works for a little while, doing all the start up stuff my app does (downloads articles to the app and presents them in a UITableView) but after awhile of articles appearing it just stops, shoots me back into Xcode and brings up the Debug Navigator sidebar, and presents this in the code window:

[image]

Mashing the "Continue program execution" button does nothing to progress the app, and I don't have any breakpoints set (it brings up lldb and the console for input weirdly enough) and I hit command-Y to disable any anyway.

Why is it doing this? There's no discernible error to fix, so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error is `EXC_ARITHMETIC`, which means you are divide a number by zero.

so you need to do is

```
if ([self.body length] == 0) return @(0);    // make sure it is not zero
_progress = // your code...
```

Comment: Why `@(0)` and not just `@0`?

Comment: @Zaph i think they have no difference